# Python scope: how to reach local variable?

Tags: python, function, variables, scope

This is my issue and I've been searching for answer for some time (I'm ashamed to admit for how long):

language: Python
issue: scope

```
def A():
    x = 0
    def B():
        x += 1
        print(x)
```

I can use x from function A to assign it's value to another variable or print it, but I can't modify x itself.

Is there a way to truly access a local variable x inside function B?
If so, how?

Comment: @AndersonGreen I am just trying to cut a line or two in my code by reusing the same variable and not creating a new one for every function inside main function

Comment: [This search query](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+nested+function+local+variable&oq=python+local+variable+nested+&gs_l=serp.3.0.0i22i30l2.125805.127964.0.128882.12.10.0.0.0.1.282.1556.1j7j2.10.0.ehm_pq_qw%2Chmrde%3D0%2Chmffs%3D10%2Chmffl%3D3%2Chmffmp%3D0-9...0...1.1.47.serp..3.9.1442.ZXAVyHgU0cA) might answer your question.

Comment: @AndersonGreen well, I found some wierd solutions... can you just tell me if it's even possible to do it without uhm ''hacks''?